# Should Debug.Assert and Debug.Fail be used liberally, and should they be left in production code?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, assertions

I am reading a book which *asserts* (pun intended) "You should load your code with *`Debug.Assert`* methods wherever you have a condition that will always be true or false."

I haven't been using these two debug methods, but it makes some sense. However, I am loathe to have this stuff littered all throughout my production code bases.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is fine, since the compiler omits it in release build. It is not bad practice, and you do not need to remove them from source (indeed, you probably shouldn't). But you ***must*** be careful:

```
Debug.Assert(SomethingImportantThatMustExecute());
```

is ***bad*** - the `SomethingImportantThatMustExecute` will be ignored in release; you must use:

```
bool result = SomethingImportantThatMustExecute()
Debug.Assert(result);
```

Basically, avoid side-effects in calls to conditional methods and partial methods.

Answer (score 11):

It depends on what you're using it for. If you're using it for assertions within your own methods, to ensure they're working properly, I think it's *okay* - but I'd prefer unit tests to validate everything I can think of if at all possible.

It's *not* a good idea (IMO) to use it to validate incoming input - e.g. parameters. In that case I believe it's much more consistent to use exceptions in the normal way of:

```
if (foo == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("foo");
}
```

In my view this behaviour should *not* change just because you're running release code.

Answer (score 4):

If you compile a Release build (using the Visual Studio project setting), all `Debug.Assert` statements will automatically be removed. So yes, use them liberally.

Comment: I know it will remove them (it removes all symbols), but I wonder if it's ugly or bad practice. I assume from your answer it's not.

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: No, in fact, it's good practice, as long as it helps you develop good code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, assertions are fine. And note that they are not only logic-checks (that's obvious) but also serve as a form of documentation, more reliable than comments.

But do think beforehand about unit-testing. If you are you going to test the Debug build the results (with respect to error logic) can be different from your Release version.

For checks that you want to be active in the Release build you can use Trace.Assert().

And nobody mentioned [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx#) yet, a richer and more structured way of checking and documenting your code.

Comment: 1+ for mentioning Code Contracts

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Debug.Assert` liberally in production code bases. `Debug.Assert` is decorated with `ConditionalAttribute`. If you compile your code in "realease" configuration, the compiler will skip calling `Debug.Assert`.